# eth-netstats and eth-net-intelligence-api communication mechanism

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

How does **eth-netstats** work with **eth-net-intelligence-api** internally?

To run ***https://ethstats.net/*** like  monitoring dashbard in Ethereum Blockchain we need to run **eth-netstats** and **eth-net-intelligence-api** simultaneously. But I can't understand how does **eth-netstats** connect with **eth-net-intelligence-api** under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They communicate via Websocket.

Net-Intelligence connects to Ethereum Network also using Websocket and then pushes data to Ethstats to feed up charts.

Geth (Websocket Server) <== (Client) Net-Intelligence (Client) ==> (Websocket Server) Netstas